# What should I put in the folder of my program if I want to embed Python to a C++ program?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I wrote a program with Qt and I embedded a `.py` file in it to do some work.

On my computer which has the Python interpreter installed, the program can run correctly, but when I run it on my roommate's PC, which has **NO** Python interpreter installed, the program crashed.

The part which is written with Qt runs well but when I push a button to call `.py` to do some work, the program crashes.

I think the problem is that I haven't put the std library and some other key files of Python into the folder of my program, but I have no idea what files should I pack into it.

So if the problem is really what I thought, what should I do to solve it?

Namely, **which files of Python should be packaged into a program to run on the PC with no Python interpreter ?**

Thanks in advance.

------------update------------------
As for the code of Python, it's just a hello-world for test and learning. I copy the whole Python34 folder into the program and the question has been solved:). Though it may not be a right way, it works.

Comment: Just required that your users have Python installed.

Also, be wary of packaging it with your project - there might be licensing issues.

Comment: Are you using something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), or are you trying to do this manually?

Comment: show your python code, and also copy and paste the traceback that is displayed when it fails

Answer (score 0):

Python's documentation has a reference manual for the [C/C++ API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html#c-api-index).
The file I believe you're referring to is `Python.h`, though I'm no expert on this. It's considerably easier to embed C than C++, and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) gives some of the more simple examples. As far as I know, you shouldn't need to worry about the interpreter for compiling to an executable.